# trying to create a basic drawing app

Tags: objective-c, iphone

This seemed simple enough:

```
- (void)touchesBegan: (CGPoint)point
{

   [path moveToPoint:point];  
}

- (void)touchesMoved: (CGPoint)point
{
    [path addLineToPoint: point]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

 }

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Here's my issue.

At the first "touch" there is a diagnoal line created next to the tap, and it's as is if I can draw just fine except for that. Screenshot here:
 [* screenshot *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip0xY.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you have old points/line data in your `path` object when `touchesBegan:` is called. Have you tried clearing/resetting your bezierpath?

Comment: no i have not - how can i do that

Comment: i tried adding removeallpoints to a touchEnd - but . everytime i [path stroke] what was already drawn dissapears